# Django SELECT Query

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-mysql

Hi Iam try to select from mysql using Django
my **models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Q

class Series(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    des  = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    img   = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    isseries  = models.IntegerField()
    istrend   = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    background_img = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    trial_url = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    imdb_id   = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    rate    = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    date = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    status    = models.IntegerField()
    isdel      = models.IntegerField()
    section_id  = models.IntegerField()
    poster_img   = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    genres       = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'series'
```

my sample Script

```
series = series_db.objects.filter(istrend=1,status=1,isdel=0).order_by('id').values()
```

i Want to SELECT all **Column** without isdel
so i remove isdel from **models.py**, but when i remove it i cant use isdel to make
WHERE isdel = 0
in mysql so i got This Error

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'isdel' into field.
```

so how i can use isdel to make a condition without select it
LIKE this Example

```
SELECT `series`.`id`, `series`.`title`, `series`.`des`, `series`.`img`, `series`.`isseries`, `series`.`istrend`, `series`.`background_img`, `series`.`trial_url`, `series`.`imdb_id`, `series`.`rate`, `series`.`date`, `series`.`status`, `series`.`section_id`, `series`.`poster_img`, `series`.`genres` FROM `series` WHERE (`series`.`isdel` = 0 AND `series`.`istrend` = '1' AND `series`.`status` = 1) ORDER BY `series`.`id` ASC
```

real Example

```
SELECT `series`.`id`, `series`.`title`, `series`.`des`, `series`.`img`, `series`.`isseries`, `series`.`istrend`, `series`.`background_img`, `series`.`trial_url`, `series`.`imdb_id`, `series`.`rate`, `series`.`date`, `series`.`status`, `series`.`isdel`, `series`.`section_id`, `series`.`poster_img`, `series`.`genres` FROM `series` WHERE (`series`.`isdel` = 0 AND `series`.`istrend` = '1' AND `series`.`status` = 1) ORDER BY `series`.`id` ASC
```

Comment: You can get the result by using a combination of Q objects and the .exclude() method

Comment: It seems that you removed `isdel`  from the `Series` model? Why do you use `series_db`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to remove the field in model just mention the column you want to retrive in `values` like this:

```
series = Series.objects.filter(
     istrend=1,status=1,isdel=0
).order_by('id').values('id', 'title', 'des')
```

I have added just three columns in values you can add all the columns except the one you don't want.

If your model has lot of field and you find it hard to add them manually one by one then you can get all the fields of the model using `_meta` and exclude the given field like this:

```
fields = [field.name for field in Series._meta.fields if field.name != 'isdel']
series = Series.objects.filter(
   istrend=1,status=1,isdel=0
).order_by('id').values(*fields)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#values)
So your query would be modified to:

```
series = series_db.objects.filter(istrend=1,status=1,isdel=0).order_by('id').values("id")
```